# I have a single switch that turns on two recessed lights over my shower but it doesn't always flip on both lights

Tags: electrical

I have a single pole switch that switches on two CFL lights over my shower and bath tub.  When I flip it on sometimes both flip on, sometimes the other one does and the other is off vice versa, sometimes both stay off.  I checked the switch and re-tightened everything and I thought I fixed it but later on same thing happened.

Comment: Would try replacing the lights, if you check out everything else.  The ballast/electronics in them might be getting wonky/failing.  Humidity near them probably not helping.

Comment: Check the seal of the light housing. Moisture maybe to blame.

Comment: Are the two lights in a single fixture?

Answer (score 0):

Switched used in residential electrical only have one contact set so if the lighting is intermittent but one is always lit it is ether a loose wire as you have checked or the ballast or lamp itself is failing time to replace them.